# Parsing date time information from CSV in Zeppelin and Spark

Tags: scala, csv, datetime, apache-spark

I'm trying to read CSV file and build up data frame.

The format of CSV like blow. I used ISO8602 date/time format for data/time string representation.

```
2015-6-29T12:0:0,b82debd63cffb1490f8c9c647ca97845,G1J8RX22EGKP,2015-6-29T12:0:5,2015-6-29T12:0:6,0QA97RAM1GIV,2015-6-29T12:0:10,2015-6-29T12:0:11,2015-6-29T12:0:12,2015-6-29T12:5:42,1
2015-6-29T12:20:0,0d60c871bd9180275f1e4104d4b7ded0,5HNB7QZSUI2C,2015-6-29T12:20:5,2015-6-29T12:20:6,KSL2LB0R6367,2015-6-29T12:20:10,2015-6-29T12:20:11,2015-6-29T12:20:12,2015-6-29T12:25:13,1
......
```

To load this data, I wrote the scala code in Zeppelin like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import sys.process._

val logCSV = sc.textFile ("log_table.csv")

case class record(
    callingTime:DateTime, 
    userID:String, 
    CID:String, 
    serverConnectionTime:DateTime, 
    serverResponseTime:DateTime, 
    connectedAgentID:String, 
    beginCallingTime:DateTime, 
    endCallingTime:DateTime, 
    Succeed:Int)


val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd'T'kk:mm:ss")

val logTable = logCSV.map(s => s.split(",") ).map(
    s => record(
            formatter.parseDateTime( s(0) ), 
            s(1),
            s(2),
            formatter.parseDateTime( s(3) ), 
            formatter.parseDateTime( s(4) ), 
            s(5),
            formatter.parseDateTime( s(6) ), 
            formatter.parseDateTime( s(7) ),            
            s(8).toInt
        )
).toDF()
```

The it made error like below. Main issue is DateTime is not serializable.

```
logCSV: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = log_table.csv MapPartitionsRDD[38] at textFile at <console>:169
defined class record
formatter: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter@46051d99
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:286)
```

Then I wonder how I handle date/time information in Scala. Could you help me?

Comment: You can try spark-csv to load the data https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: Oh, it can be good solution. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) isn't serialiable, if you use the [parseMillis](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseMillis-java.lang.String-) method of [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you'll get a long, which is toll-free bridged to Long, which is Serializable. To get the DateTime back from the Long, use the `DateTime(longInstance.longValue())` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into the challenge that your formatter isn't serializeable. Instead you can construct the formatter inside of the map (or you could use mapPartitions and construct it inside of the mapPartitions so you only have to construct one formatter per-partition).

Comment: Constructing the formatter inside the map didn't fix this issue in my case. :<

Comment: Looking at this, it seems like you might also need to convert the Joda DateTime to Spark SQL's internal date time format (see DateTimeUtils in Spark SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answers from everybody!! I decided to use `Timestamp` because it's possible to serialize and Dataframe support this. I revised the code like below.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Record(
    callingTime:Timestamp,
    userID:String, 
    CID:String,
    succeed:Int)


val dataFrame = logCSV.map( _.split(",") ).map(
    r => Record(
            Timestamp.valueOf(r(0).replace("T", " ") ),
            r(1),
            r(2),
            r(10).toInt
        )
    ).toDF()
dataFrame.registerTempTable("dataFrame")
```

The date/time format in my data is [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601). So I need to change 'T' to '  ' for `Timestamp`. Then `Timestamp.valueof` can be used.